# Cannot erase external NOR flash memory after successful read, write using stm32

Tags: flash, stm32

I am using STM32L496ZG to interface ISSI IS29GL064-70TLET nor flash by using HAL library. I used CUBE MX to generate the code and running code on Keil compiler. I am able to detect device ID, write and read block. But unable to erase data. HAL_NOR_GetSTATUS reurns success.

I have used example code provided in application note AN4761.

Erase code snippet is below:

The status returns erase success. But the contents are still the same, they don't turn to ones at all.

Can any one please help me on this?

```
#define WRITE_READ_ADDR 0x8000

#define  NOR_BANK_ADDR 0x64000000

HAL_NOR_ReturnToReadMode(&hnor1);

HAL_NOR_Erase_Block(&hnor1, WRITE_READ_ADDR, NOR_BANK_ADDR);
```

/* Return the NOR memory status */

```
if(HAL_NOR_GetStatus(&hnor1, NOR_BANK_ADDR, NOR_TIMEOUT_VALUE) !=

HAL_NOR_STATUS_SUCCESS)

{

/* Erase Error */

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) "Erase error" , 12, 100);

return NOR_STATUS_ERASE_ERROR;

}
```

I tried changing the sector address but to no avail. I also searched internet a lot but did not find solution for this problem.
The init code is a below :

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_Init_Structure;
GPIO_Init_Structure.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_Init_Structure.Pull      = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init_Structure.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;


GPIO_Init_Structure.Alternate = GPIO_AF12_FMC;
GPIO_Init_Structure.Pin   = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_4 
| GPIO_PIN_5 |GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9 | GPIO_PIN_10 | 
GPIO_PIN_11 |GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_Init_Structure);
GPIO_Init_Structure.Pin   =   GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_8 | 
GPIO_PIN_9 | GPIO_PIN_10 | GPIO_PIN_11 |GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 | 
GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_Init_Structure);

/** Perform the NOR1 memory initialization sequence
*/
hnor1.Instance = FMC_NORSRAM_DEVICE;
hnor1.Extended = FMC_NORSRAM_EXTENDED_DEVICE;
/* hnor1.Init */
hnor1.Init.NSBank = FMC_NORSRAM_BANK2;
hnor1.Init.DataAddressMux = FMC_DATA_ADDRESS_MUX_DISABLE;
hnor1.Init.MemoryType = FMC_MEMORY_TYPE_NOR;
hnor1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
hnor1.Init.BurstAccessMode = FMC_BURST_ACCESS_MODE_DISABLE;
hnor1.Init.WaitSignalPolarity = FMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_POLARITY_LOW;
hnor1.Init.WaitSignalActive = FMC_WAIT_TIMING_BEFORE_WS;
hnor1.Init.WriteOperation = FMC_WRITE_OPERATION_ENABLE;
hnor1.Init.WaitSignal = FMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_DISABLE;
hnor1.Init.ExtendedMode = FMC_EXTENDED_MODE_DISABLE;
hnor1.Init.AsynchronousWait = FMC_ASYNCHRONOUS_WAIT_ENABLE;
hnor1.Init.WriteBurst = FMC_WRITE_BURST_DISABLE;
hnor1.Init.ContinuousClock = FMC_CONTINUOUS_CLOCK_SYNC_ONLY;
hnor1.Init.WriteFifo = FMC_WRITE_FIFO_ENABLE;
hnor1.Init.PageSize = FMC_PAGE_SIZE_NONE;
/* Timing */
Timing.AddressSetupTime = 0x03;
Timing.AddressHoldTime = 1;
Timing.DataSetupTime = 0x7;
Timing.BusTurnAroundDuration = 0;
Timing.CLKDivision = 2;
Timing.DataLatency = 2;
Timing.AccessMode = FMC_ACCESS_MODE_B;
/* ExtTiming */
if (HAL_NOR_Init(&hnor1, &Timing, NULL) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler( );
}
}
```

[NOR Flash Manual Sector Erase section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeI17.png)

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_NOR_Erase_Block(NOR_HandleTypeDef *hnor, 
uint32_t BlockAddress, uint32_t Address)
{
uint32_t deviceaddress;
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

/* Check the NOR controller state */
if (hnor->State == HAL_NOR_STATE_BUSY)
{
return HAL_BUSY;
}
else if (hnor->State == HAL_NOR_STATE_READY)
{
/* Process Locked */
__HAL_LOCK(hnor);

/* Update the NOR controller state */
hnor->State = HAL_NOR_STATE_BUSY;

/* Select the NOR device address */
if (hnor->Init.NSBank == FMC_NORSRAM_BANK1)
{
  deviceaddress = NOR_MEMORY_ADRESS1;
}
else if (hnor->Init.NSBank == FMC_NORSRAM_BANK2)
{
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) 
"\r\nNOR_MEMORY_ADRESS2 in Erase Block" , 34, 100);
  deviceaddress = NOR_MEMORY_ADRESS2;
}
else if (hnor->Init.NSBank == FMC_NORSRAM_BANK3)
{
  deviceaddress = NOR_MEMORY_ADRESS3;
}
else /* FMC_NORSRAM_BANK4 */
{
  deviceaddress = NOR_MEMORY_ADRESS4;
}

/* Send block erase command sequence */
// if (hnor->CommandSet == NOR_AMD_FUJITSU_COMMAND_SET)
    if(1)
{
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) 
"\r\nNOR_AMD_FUJITSU_COMMAND_SET in Erase Block" , 44, 100);
  NOR_WRITE(NOR_ADDR_SHIFT(((uint32_t)0x64000000), 
uwNORMemoryDataWidth, NOR_CMD_ADDRESS_FIRST), 
NOR_CMD_DATA_FIRST);
  NOR_WRITE(NOR_ADDR_SHIFT(((uint32_t)0x64000000), 
uwNORMemoryDataWidth, NOR_CMD_ADDRESS_SECOND), 
NOR_CMD_DATA_SECOND);
  NOR_WRITE(NOR_ADDR_SHIFT(((uint32_t)0x64000000), 
uwNORMemoryDataWidth, NOR_CMD_ADDRESS_THIRD),
             NOR_CMD_DATA_CHIP_BLOCK_ERASE_THIRD);
  NOR_WRITE(NOR_ADDR_SHIFT(((uint32_t)0x64000000), 
uwNORMemoryDataWidth, NOR_CMD_ADDRESS_FOURTH),
            NOR_CMD_DATA_CHIP_BLOCK_ERASE_FOURTH);
  NOR_WRITE(NOR_ADDR_SHIFT(((uint32_t)0x64000000), 
uwNORMemoryDataWidth, NOR_CMD_ADDRESS_FIFTH),
            NOR_CMD_DATA_CHIP_BLOCK_ERASE_FIFTH);
  NOR_WRITE((uint32_t)(BlockAddress + (0x64000000U)), 
NOR_CMD_DATA_BLOCK_ERASE);
}
else if (hnor->CommandSet == NOR_INTEL_SHARP_EXT_COMMAND_SET)
{
  NOR_WRITE((BlockAddress + Address), NOR_CMD_BLOCK_UNLOCK);
  NOR_WRITE((BlockAddress + Address), NOR_CMD_CONFIRM);
  NOR_WRITE((BlockAddress + Address), NOR_CMD_BLOCK_ERASE);
  NOR_WRITE((BlockAddress + Address), NOR_CMD_CONFIRM);
}
else
{
  /* Primary command set not supported by the driver */
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) "HAL_ERROR in 
Erase Block" , 24, 100);
  status = HAL_ERROR;
}

/* Check the NOR memory status and update the controller state */
hnor->State = HAL_NOR_STATE_READY;

/* Process unlocked */
__HAL_UNLOCK(hnor);
}
else
{
return HAL_ERROR;
}
return status;

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you said you can write? What does that mean? You can't write flash without having it erased first. So can you actually write things? Or can you write things only once at every location, and then you can't erase it? Also, please style your code as code, it's hard to read

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually this is first time I am trying to access external nor flash (parallel interface). 
I am writing the data, able to read it back. But can't erase it. So I tested erase operation at the end.  So erase operation should be performed first before writing, right? But it won't work.

Comment: Yes Ilya. I am writing data at any location once and can't erase it.

Comment: Yes. Flash memory is built in such a way, that you can only program bit 1 to bit 0, but not 0 to 1 without erasing. That's why you need to erase a sector every time you want to write something (STM32 will give flash error if you write to non-erased place). Also, you can't erase just one byte or just one word, it has to be a sector (so if you want to preserve the rest of the data in that sector, you need to read it out and preserve that data in RAM, erase, and write it back in, which is inefficient and costs 1 Flash erase cycle).

Comment: Have you found other implementations online? It could be your bank address is off, erase function must work, so I would start with validating the parameters you pass to it.

Comment: Not sure about other implementations. This worked for other operations so erase must work as you said. Don't know where  am missing ?
The parameters include NOR Handle pointer which is used for initialization, bank address(0x640000) and a target address( tried for 0x01F8000, 0x8000).

Comment: Hi @Ilya, thanks for the information. I tried erase first then write. I could over write the contents in the memory. Otherwise, it won't write new data successfully as you said.
But now, i want to erase the contents to make data all 1s. That is not happening. The read command returns same contents when it was written after erase. Can I know what step I am missing? 
Like if I want to erase entire chip, I can't.
Thanks

Comment: have you checked the reference manual for FMC (or whatever you drive it with) and datasheet for the flash? Some flash memories (both internal and external) require to be "unlocked" before they can be erased - sending special command or writing special sequence to special register, after which one erase command can be performed. Check for something like that in the documentation.

Comment: Ok. I will check let you know.

Comment: Yes @Ilya, the sector erase command sequence is :> 2 unlock cycles, followed by a setup command, then again followed by 2 unlock cycles and a erase command. This is included in code.

Comment: Can anyone guide me?

Comment: My problem is, I can write only once to any new address, but cannot re-write again. So still, I could not make erase work.  I need help to get it resolved.  Looking for any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: My only suggestion at this point to do it all on registers without HAL. It will be literally a couple of lines. At least you can compare if it works.

Comment: I tried writing my own erase code with help of some expert, but the situation remains same, cannot erase the blocks/sector. I think I am missing something else and unable figure out due to lack of my knowledge.  Am badly looking for a way out.  Plz help.

Comment: When I erase SPI ROMs (with BIOS - on laptops), sometimes erase/write fails because there is a spike in the consumption current during erasing, which pulls the voltage down if the power source is not all-powerful, or if there are long wires with more resistance (and thus more voltage drop as higher current passes through them). Even tho I have a BIOS Flash programmer, I usually hook up an external power supply because of that - and only then it works reliably. Also, I recommend a beefy capacitor (such as 10uF, or 22uF) next to flash ic power pin in addition to a small decoupling cap.